# Is there any way to programmatically fix DOM/CSS on-the-fly in web browser?

Tags: css, dom, google-chrome

For example, opening the front page of [translate.ru](https://www.translate.ru/), it contains a lot of banners. But by the Developer Tools in Chrome it's possible to go through the page and tweak CSS in-place (mostly adding 'display: none') and eventually the page looks this way:

[image]
<sub>(source: [demin.ws](http://demin.ws/images/blog/translate-ru-clean.png))</sub>

So, a question: is there any APIs or existing extensions for Chrome allowing programmatically change DOM/CSS on the page? I saw similar Chrome extensions allowing to tweak Gmail and Google Reader, but it was specifically for those websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha).

[image]

Comment: I wish it could XPath.